# How do you set up 2 threadpools that work next to eachother?

Tags: java, multithreading, pdf, threadpool, bmp

I have a question about threadpooling.

This is the situation I have:
Somewhere from a backendservice we receive a list of pdf files.
One by one these pdf pages first need to be converted to .bmp files.
After this conversion these bmps need to be printed.

The problem is that both the converting and the printing tasks take a while to  complete and I want to make this process go quicker because else it would take quite a while before somebody sees something coming out of the printer.

A solution I thought off was to create 2 ThreadPools: one for the converting stuff and one for the printing stuff.

These would be my Threadpools:

```
ExecutorService convertPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

ExecutorService printPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

A `convertPool` with 10 threads to convert the pages of a pdf to bmps.
When this is done, the created bmps will be send to the printPool. This is a single thread because there can always be just one printing.

But now comes my question: 
so the convertPool has done it's work with the first pdf and send all Future Tasks to the PrintPool to get printed.
But when the printPool is busy, I want the `convertPool` to begin already with the 2nd pdf. So that when the PrintPool has done it's work with printing the bmps from the first pdf, it can immmediately start working with the bmp printing of the 2nd pdf because these are already created.

But how can I set this mechanism up? Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you have a correctly implemented thread pool, I don't see how adding a second makes it go any faster.  You only have so many CPU cores and you can't go faster than that.  If the problem is IO bound then no additional CPU will help.  Just use one thread pool, and *profile* the app to find where the slowdown is.

Comment: First.. call `convertPool.submit` in a for loop for all tasks.. and add the futures to an `arrayList`.. then loop through the list and call `printPool.submit(job.get())`..  so now it waits for the future to complete.. but still prints in order. In any case, this should be more than fine. Not sure where your bottleneck is..

Answer (score 0):

- you can use the same executor to execute a runnable for printing job.
- in that runnable you can reference a List of futures produced from
  execution of callables that are in-fact processing your PDFs.
- the list would of-course have a global reference.
- now you can use semaphores with limited permits say (10) and while any callable
  ends execution, it can release a permit which the runnable would
  try to acquire beforehand and thus stay in a blocked state as none would be available.

  **NOTE: Every PDF processing Callable would accquire a permit at the start of its execution.**
- your runnable can be try acquirng the permit before accessing any
  future that returns the status of `Done()` as true and can release the
  permit at the tail of iteration.
- ones all the taks have finished execution or when 10 permits are available again, you can terminate the executor by executuing `shutdownNow()` thus terminating runnable.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You can submit as many conversion tasks as you like to your converter pool. It will execute them as soon as it can and queue those that can't be serviced by a thread yet. When each conversion task completes, it can submit itself to the print pool, which will also queue tasks as needed. This is a basic skeleton of what I mean:

```
class Conversion implements Runnable {
    Consumer<Conversion> onCompletion;

    Conversion(Consumer<Conversion> onCompletion) {
        this.onCompletion = onCompletion;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ... conversion code. You could Thread.sleep()
        // here to simulate the conversion work taking up
        // some time.

        // (now we're done converting)
        onCompletion.accept(this);
    }
}

class Print implements Runnable {
    Print(Conversion c) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...run() method, etc.
}

// Example of submitting a conversion task to the executor
convertPool.submit(new Conversion(c -> printPool.submit(new Print(c))));
```